# Calling a phtml file using controller

Tags: magento2

Hi am trying to call a phtml file using controller but the form does not comes within the layout it goes above the page but i want to be within the layout below is my code kindly please take a look

```
$block = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Rfq')
               ->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::rfq_form.phtml')
               ->toHtml();
             $this->getResponse()->setBody($block);
            $this->_view->renderLayout();
            $this->_view->loadLayout();
```

**update**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Rfq" name="rfq_form" template="Vendor_Module::rfq_form.phtml"  />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

it gives blank when i hit controller

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but creating blocks like this is not the best way to do it. You should add the blocks from the layout files.

Comment: Are you using any layout xml to place your file on the desired place?

Comment: no am not suing any xml here just trying to make a call using controller only

Comment: i tried but it gives a blank page when i hit controller

Comment: can you give your controller path , layout file name and routes.xml file content

Comment: requestforquote/index/index

Answer (score 1):

**Check below code may be it will help.**

```
/**
     * @var Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context     $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory

    ) {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__(' heading '));

        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('VENDOR\EXTENSION\Block\blockname')
                ->setTemplate('VENDOR_EXTENSION::callingfile.phtml')
                ->toHtml();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($block);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: there was an issue with my controller i forgot to return result page factory due to which the layout was not working very strange

Comment: @Pramod please accept the answer if it is helpful.